# Issues getting device/user location with iOS App, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

Setup:

1. Xcode 7.3 (7D175)
2. Swift 2
3. Device is an iPad with iOS 9.3.1

I have a Swift class called `LocationUtility`, I am using it like so in a ViewController:

```
 let locationUtil = LocationUtility()
 locationUtil.initLocationManager()
```

The `initLocationManager()` function sets the `CLLocationManager.delegate` to my `LocationUtility` class:

```
func initLocationManager() {
    seenError = false
    locationFixAchieved = false
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

The following delegate func is never being called:

`func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])`

I have `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` string set in my `Info.plist`

On my iPad, Privacy -> Location Services is Enabled.

**My LocationUtility class is something a put together with, mostly code from other stackoverflow questions and answers about location functionality in Swift and iOS 8 and beyond. From my perspective I have all the right settings in my APP and on my device to be receiving location information.**

Here is my complete `LocationUtility` class source code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class LocationUtility: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var locationStatus : NSString = "Not Started"
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
    var seenError : Bool = false
    var locationFixAchieved : Bool = false
    var currentLocation:CLLocation? = nil

    func initLocationManager() {
        seenError = false
        locationFixAchieved = false
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            //locationManager.delegate = self
            //locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }

    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        print("LocationUtility -> didFailWithError()")
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        if (seenError == false) {
            seenError = true
            print(error)
        }

    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print("LocationUtility -> didUpdateLocations()")
        if (locationFixAchieved == false) {
            locationFixAchieved = true
            //var locationArray = locations as NSArray
            currentLocation = locations.last! as CLLocation
            let coord = currentLocation!.coordinate

            print("user current location")
            print(coord.latitude)
            print(coord.longitude)
        }
    }

    // authorization status
   func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
            print("LocationUtility -> didChangeAuthorizationStatus()!")

            var shouldIAllow = false

            switch status {
            case CLAuthorizationStatus.Restricted:
                locationStatus = "Restricted Access to location"
            case CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied:
                locationStatus = "User denied access to location"
            case CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined:
                locationStatus = "Status not determined"
            default:
                locationStatus = "Allowed to location Access"
                shouldIAllow = true
            }

            if (shouldIAllow == true) {
                NSLog("Location to Allowed")
                // Start location services
                locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            } else {
                NSLog("Denied access: \(locationStatus)")
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Roee84 I changed my question "title" and edited my question then so I could further assistance beyond my delegate question, thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Does the `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` method ever get called? If so, with what value(s) for `status`?

Comment: didChangeAuthorizationStatus does not get called either, it makes me think there is something wrong with the delegate I am setting but my LocationUtility class does implement CLLocationManagerDelegate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symptoms you describe strongly suggest that your `LocationUtility` instance is getting deallocated, which deallocates the `CLLocationManager` and stops the entire process. It's not clear where you're instantiating `LocationUtility` but you need to make sure it's some place where the instance will remain "live" in memory while `CLLocationManager` does its things. If the view controller is deallocated, for example, then its instance vars will be deallocated, which looks like it probably includes your location manager.

Your question initially asked if the location manager had to be in the app delegate. It doesn't, of course, but it **does** have to be someplace that can prevent it from being deallocated while location updates are in progress.

If you're unsure when the `LocationManager` is getting deallocated, try implementing `deinit` on it and setting a breakpoint on that method.

Comment: Yup I thinking something along these lines but was making the assumption that my ViewController WAS NOT being deallocated while I remained on my mapping screen in the app, but I will test deinit here and get back to you, thanks for the advice